# How to remove non repeating character from string in SQL using fuction or SP?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have 2 columns

1st have string like: `'7,8,9,0,3'`
2nd have string like: `'7,8,5,6,1'`

I want output like this: `9,0,3` and `5,6,1` or both combined as `9,0,3,5,6,1`

Comment: What Database do you use ?

Comment: If you include some code that you have tried, you will have higher chance to get more replies from other users. Here users try to help if you are stuck, they don't like to write full code for you.

Comment: can you please clarify which database you are using. Also please confirm if these are two columns of table or these are two variables.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the below code to SP:

```
DECLARE @Col1 VARCHAR(100)=    '7,8,9,0,3', @Col2 VARCHAR(100)=    '7,8,5,6,1'


DECLARE @Table1 Table (Col1 VARCHAR(100))

DECLARE @Table2 Table (Col2 VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES ( @Col1)

INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (@Col2)



;with tmp( Data,Col1) as (

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),LEFT(Col1, CHARINDEX(',',Col1+',')-1)),
    STUFF(Col1, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Col1+','), '')
FROM @Table1
union all
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),LEFT(Col1, CHARINDEX(',',Col1+',')-1)),
    STUFF(Col1, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Col1+','), '')
FROM tmp
WHERE Col1>''
)
select ID = IDENTITY(INT,1,1),CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),Data) AS Col1
INTO #T1
from tmp

;with tmp( Data,Col2) as (
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),LEFT(Col2, CHARINDEX(',',Col2+',')-1)),
    STUFF(Col2, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Col2+','), '')
FROM @Table2
union all
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),LEFT(Col2, CHARINDEX(',',Col2+',')-1)),
    STUFF(Col2, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Col2+','), '')
FROM tmp
WHERE Col2>''
)
select ID = IDENTITY(INT,1,1),CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),Data) AS Col2
INTO #T2
from tmp

SELECT ID = IDENTITY(INT,1,1),Col1
INTO #T3
FROM
(
    SELECT Col1
    FROM #T1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Col1
        FROM #T1
        INTERSECT
        SELECT Col2
        FROM #T2
    )T3

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Col2
    FROM #T2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Col1
        FROM #T1
        INTERSECT
        SELECT Col2
        FROM #T2
    )T4
)T5

SELECT DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT ',' + Col1
                           FROM #T3 T1
                           --WHERE T1.ID=T2.Id
                           FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
FROM #T3 T2

DROP TABLE #T1,#T2,#T3
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/GHGCT21169)

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is full outer join on the same table between the 2 columns.

```
SELECT distinct A.name1,B.name2
FROM <TABLE> A full outer join <TABLE> B  on A.name1 = B.name2
where A.name1 is null or B.name2 is null
```